# Enable account selector in a CloudWatch read only account

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

We have a cross-account cross-region implementation in CloudWatch, where the idea is to have monitoring centralized in a HUB account that can read CloudWatch information from other “spoke” accounts.

The implementation is complete, and I can access CloudWatch in the HUB account and see all the information from other accounts with no problem (from my admin account).

**The problem**:

We have a Tier 1 team (a first level NOC) that will receive the alarm notifications CloudWatch generates. This team role uses CloudWatchReadOnlyAccess managed policy for them to see CloudWatch.

We found that, in order to see the account/region dropdown option, each account has to go to CloudWatch settings and manually enable the ‘View cross-account cross-region’ option. Even if the Tier1 team would manually go to activate this setting, they are unable to do so. I imagine this is because their role is a Read Only one.

[Clicking the enable button from a read only account has no effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/po0l4.jpg)

•   What permission can be added to these roles in order to allow them to enable the account selector? I wouldn’t want to give them CloudWatch full access, as the team does not need to modify/create/remove alarms.

Comment: Did you found out an solution to this? I have exactly the same issue now..

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? Unfortunately, I'm unable to enable this even with CloudWatchFullAccess.

Comment: No, sadly I never got a solution. I escalated this to AWS support but and to a dedicated engineer we had and nobody new the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a user-specific setting, so it needs to be done for each user.

CloudWatch Dashboard >> Settings >> View cross-region cross-account data >> Edit >> Check the box "Show selector in the console" and select the type of selector (Account Id Input, AWS Organization account selector, Custom account selector) >> Save changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this permission and try again...

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:GetRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::<AWS Account Id>:role/aws-service-role/cloudwatch-crossaccount.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForCloudWatchCrossAccount"
        }
    ]
}
```